# how to handle the exception Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. while adding the data to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my application i need to add data to database and display it in gridview below is the code that i used without adding id it works fine but after adding Id in my insert query and update query i am getting this exception as `Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`How can i handle this exception as i am new to this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnection "].ConnectionString;
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from  TableName";
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, " TableName ");
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataRow drow = ds.Tables["TableName"].NewRow();
        drow["id"] = TextBox1.Text;
        drow["Name"] = TextBox2.Text;
        drow["Designation"] = TextBox3.Text;
        drow["Mobile_No"] = TextBox4.Text;
        drow["Address"] = TextBox5.Text;

        ds.Tables["TableName "].Rows.Add(drow);
        da.Update(ds, " TableName ");
        string script = @"<script language=""javascript"">
        alert('Information have been Saved Successfully.......!!!!!.');
       </script>;";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myJScript1", script);
    }
```

Comment: I think your data is updating correctly...But the message is not showing because the code never entering these block                                                          `if (IsUpdated)
            {
                lblErrorMsg.Text = "Details updated successfully!";
                lblErrorMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }`

Comment: Isn't there an ID value for each record? There should be a unique primary key and it should be used in the `WHERE` clause of the update query. As the query is written now, the record will not be found if `FirstName` is modified.

Comment: Please read up on using [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx). Especially as here, you appear to be incorporating user input from a website directly into an SQL Statement - this opens up the opportunity for SQL Injection, which *should* be one of the most well known potential security holes to avoid these days.

Answer (score 0):

Since Id is most probably a numeric value, don't try to assign it a string value, instead generate the SQL code for the number:

```
"[...]values(" + Id + ",'" + [...]
```

instead of (pay attention to the `'` sign)

```
"[...]values('" + Id + "','" + [...]
```

However, as Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out, you should use SQL Parameters instead of writing the whole statement as string.

If your Id value is defined as auto-assigned identity column, just remove it from the value list of your statement.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is **Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.**

So either both Sql server table column and C# id column must be varchar or varbinary.
**VarBinary(sqltype)=Byte[] (.Net)**

```
    byte[] ID=SqlDbType.VarBinary;
    string query = "insert into RegistrationDetails1(Id,FirstName,LastName,MiddleName,Email,LoginID,CreatedDate,Role,Password,Activestatus,passwordstatus,Dept,Eno,Customer) values('" + ID + "','" + txtfname.Text + "','" + txtlname.Text + "','" + txtmname.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + LoginId[0].ToString() + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + ddlRole.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','" + Password + "','" + "1" + "','" + "1" + "','" + Dept + "','" + txteno.Text + "','" + Customer + "')";
```